# How to install additional language packs on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 15.04, language-support

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04, and every spell checker on the machine, and language etc, is in English (US), however I want to change that to English (UK), and I want to add support for Russian so that I can change to that when I wish, and tell my spell checkers to also change to that. In the normal Ubuntu 15.04 installation there is a language support section, and apparently in earlier versions of Ubuntu Gnome, however in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 I cannot find this functionality.

So I believe my question is clear, in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 how do I add additional language packs (specifically English (UK) and Russian)?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The terminal way

The terminal way is excellent described in [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/651467/367165) of [@GunnarHjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson) and in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/654028/367165) of [@Serg](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/serg).

---

### The GUI way

Start the *Language Support* via GNOME Shell or `language-selector-gnome` (GNOME 3.14) or `gnome-language-selector` (GNOME 3.16) in a terminal.

[image]

Click <kbd>Install / Remove Languages…</kbd> and select one or more languages to install

[image]

Comment: If I don't see the languages I want here, what can I do? I have the ISO but not internet. Adding my ISO to the sources helps?

Comment: this GUI method does not work in the case of dialects. For example, if you have English US installed, it does not allow you to find English UK

Answer (score 6):

Here's a few command line tools you might not have been aware of.

1. The good-old `apt-get`!

   Search with `apt-cache search language-pack-gnome-xx`, there `xx` is the code for language. In your case, if you want russian – `apt-cache search language-pack-gnome-ru`. There's two packages, actually, `language-pack-gnome-ru` and `language-pack-gnome-ru-base`. Running `sudo apt-get install language-pack-gnome-ru` tells me:

   ```
   The following extra packages will be installed:
     firefox-locale-ru language-pack-gnome-ru-base language-pack-ru
     language-pack-ru-base
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     firefox-locale-ru language-pack-gnome-ru language-pack-gnome-ru-base
     language-pack-ru language-pack-ru-base
   ```

   So as you can see, base package gets installed automatically – no need to worry about that.
2. Long time ago I had to write a script that automatically sets language input and turns out `gsettings` does that quite well.

   Run `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources  sources` to get your selection for current input sources available. If you want to add a language source, here's my example of adding Spanish to my list:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources  sources "[('xkb', 'us'),('xkb','es'),('xkb','zh')]"
   ```

   Notice the comas and single quotes, as well as double quotes. Very important for syntax.
3. `check-language-support` command.

   This neat little command will help you find out which language packs you are missing, you can target a specific language with `-l` or `--language=LANG` flags, as well as `--show-installed`. Neat, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of two ways. Either you install Language Support:

```
sudo apt-get install language-selector-gnome
```

and do it from there. Optionally you can just run these commands in a terminal window:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/locale-langpack/ru
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used your code in my answer, see the history. I will remove it again.

Comment: @A.B.: Aha.. I should have looked at the history. Sorry for blaming you by flagging the answer. I noticed an "unaccept" entry in my reputation log, and got pissed when I saw my answer almost copied with a couple of pics added. Now I see it was the OP who 'merged' our answers and moved the accept mark. Actually, the 'merged' answer was better IMO, and personally - in the light of what I know now - I wouldn't mind if you changed it back. Sorry again.

Comment: I have added an extra section in my answer for your solution. I thinks, this is better for you and for me :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise what I could cause by merging them together...

Answer (score -1):

What i did was:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade *lang*es* (in case I want to install Spanish)
```

This is to search any language pack which name contains `lang` and `es`, with leading letters and trailing letters.

And from the packages listed, I chose to install `language-pack-gnome-es`, and so on. Actually after installing this you hardly need anything else.