# How to install additional language pack on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Tags: gnome, 15.10, language-support

I am now running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I already [asked this question for 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/651447/364819), but now I was wondering if there was any change with the new release on this and whether I still need to install GNOME Language Selector third-party application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, starting with Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 3.16+ there is now the option to install language packs through the UI rather than by having to install a third-party application.

For instance, if you wanted to install `Korean (Korea, Republic of)` you would open the `gnome-control-center` and go to `Region & Language`:

[image]

Which should take you to:

[image]

Then click `Language`:

[image]

Which should open:

[image]

After that click on the dots:

[image]

Then search for `Korean`, click on it in the results list and then click `Done`:

[image]

After that you should get several different dialogs which will allow you to see what will be installed and how much room it will take etc, just select the `Install` and `Continue` buttons and then enter your password in the password prompt, this will install all the things necessary for the Korean language pack on your machine.